# Windows Authentication in ASP.NET gives 401

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

First of all, I have looked for a solution in the existing posts, but I didn't find a solution that helped me. Here is my issue:

- There is an ASPX, I am trying to invoke from an ASP .NET Web Service application. The target URL is: "http://server.company.com/Test/something.aspx?Id=ABCDEF&firstname=Matt&lastname=Damon".
- The target web service requires us to authenticate with our AD (windows) login.
- I have tried adding ("identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\userid" password="pwd123" />") and it did not work.
- When I open the target URL in a browser, it asks for my windows login and once I provide it, everything works as expected.
- I have also tried "CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials" and other recommendations I read online.
- Everytime, I get this error: ***System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized***.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please share your relevant code for calling the ASPX.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with just a change to the web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
        <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: There was another webservice that did the same thing I wanted. I could use it without authentication.